# Jest/Typescript: Importing a File Breaks Import in Another File

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm having a strange issue with my unit tests and Jest that I have no idea how to solve. When I import a file in `file2.ts`, the import of the same file in `file1.ts` becomes `undefined`. The application builds and runs, but the unit tests no longer work and throw the following error in `file1.ts`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getModel' of undefined
```

This is the code:

**file1.ts**

```
import users from '../users';

const model = users.getModel();

...
```

**file2.ts**

```
import users from '../../users';

const model = users.getModel();

...
```

**users.ts**

```
export class User {
  getModel() {
    ...
  }
}

export default new User();
```

The unit test for `file2.ts` throws the error above for `file1.ts` even though I am only running the unit test for `file2.ts` specifically.

If I comment out `const model = users.getModel();` in `file2.ts`, then the error isn't thrown.

Here are my `tsconfig.json` and my `jest.config.js` files:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es6",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: './test-coverage'
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a circular dependency, but I can't tell from the truncated example code you posted. But circular deps can cause imports to show up as undefined due to race conditions. You can use the [eslint-plugin-import/no-cycle](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-cycle.md) rule to check for circular deps, and then refactor them out of your code base.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I didn't think I had a circular dependency, but I installed and ran the eslint plugin anyway just to make sure. It confirmed I don't unfortunately. That probably would have been a fairly easy fix.

Comment: It wasn't a circular import, but it was a race condition elsewhere. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Cool! Glad to be of help 